# Drag image from a webpage and display it in silverlight canvas?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am working on silverlight image drag and drop but later i came to know that silverlight drag and drop is possible only from local filesystem.It is not fetching image source from external webpage,kindly put forth your ideas how can i drag images from a webpage and drop onto the silverlight application.

Comment: Why do you want images from a webpage? Can you please explain the actual problem you are trying to solve?